# How to verify if three numbers are equal using logical operators (with a restriction!)?

Tags: logic

Please read below, as there is an important restriction to this question.

Think of a number as an array of 0's and 1's. The logical operators I want to use are the usual: AND, OR, XOR, NAND, NOT (negation or "!").

To check if TWO numbers a and b are equal, simply do:

NOT(a XOR b)

This will be an array of 1's only if the two numbers are equal.

Thus to check if three numbers are equal I could simply do:

NOT(a XOR b) AND NOT(b XOR c)

However, the restriction is that I cannot write any of the numbers a,b,c more than once. So I need something similar to this:

(a OPERATOR1 b) OPERATOR2 c,

where each of the numbers a,b,c appear exactly once.

I'd be happy to answer questions on the context of this question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: idk if this will help, but i got- a'b'+bc+ac' as simplest form in AND & OR form. which is nothing close to NAND or XOR, _i think_.

Comment: got it! will post soon. i might be wrong...

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that Not(a XOR b) AND NOT(b XOR c) is as concise as you're going to get.

It's the most compact expression which will return $1$ if and only if $a = b = c$. All other modes of expressing this with the connectives you list involve multiple appearances of one or more of $a, b, c$.

If you can use BOOLE ($\Leftrightarrow$): then you can limit to one occurrence of each of a, b, c:

$$a \Leftrightarrow b \Leftrightarrow c$$

---

See for example: [Wolfram's elaboration](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=not%28a%20xor%20b%29%20and%20not%28b%20xor%20c%29)

Comment: You are missing a parenthesis.

Comment: About $\Leftrightarrow$: Not really, since this is properly written as $(a\Leftrightarrow b)\mathbf{AND}(b\Leftrightarrow c)$, then you are still using one of them twice.

Comment: wircho, it is considered a valid (and standard) *minimal form*. It's expansion involves AND, but then so does XOR:  the expansion of XOR involves (a OR b) AND NOT (a AND b)

Comment: I know it is right in mathematical language but my point is that you cannot write it like that in any programming language. The expression (a==b==c) is understood as (a==b)==c which just compares c to a boolean value.

Comment: Thanks for sayin so that i am near 15k.

Comment: @Babak You are so close...by tomorrow, I bet, and well deserved.

Comment: @amWhy: Yes I hope so, but I am making some very simple question than others like you and other Masters do here. I imagine myself here as a amateur who are sitting on the shore of a very vast sea and just play with water while you are on a boat in the middle of this stormy sea. ;-)

Comment: The questions you answer aren't always simple...you do a great job, e.g., in group theory (and across the board)...it takes compassion and talent, like you have, to help with simpler questions too, (many of which I answer, as well), because we cannot assume all the tools we may know are known to the OP.  So no need to belittle your contributions. You have a helpful, cooperative, and eager-to-help style that I wish more of the "super high rep" users employed regularly!

Comment: @BabakS Anyway, I'm glad to see you're doing well, and it's clear you English is getting good! Personally, I'm having a not-so-good day in many not-so-good ways :-/

Comment: @amWhy: Me too. I pray for you to defeat all obsolesces, amWhy. :-)

Comment: @amWhy: New day has come, as Celine songs. 10k + for you.  ;-)

Comment: Thanks, @BabakS. I appreciate that.

Comment: you could check for a false (a XOR b) OR (b XOR c)   too, to make things more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** My proof is not valid, as I forgot about $\mathtt{XOR}$. Nevertheless, I will leave it here, it still might be useful for somebody.

**Edit 2:** As I don't know how to simply fix this issue, I will give a short informal argument based on information theory: with $x_i$ being used only once, we have only 1 bit (the output of some sub-expression) to convey 2 bits of information:

- whether the previous comparison succeed,
- whether we are comparing to $0$ or to $1$.

It is possible for $n = 2$, because we don't need to propagate the "previous comparisons succeeded" bit (there is no previous comparisons). If only we could use every $x_i$ twice, it would be possible for any $n$, because we could implement (0).

---

This is impossible. As different indices/bits of input numbers are treated independently, WLOG we can assume that all the input $x_i \in \{0,1\}$. So we have a sequence $x_i$ and want to construct a logical expression which is equivalent to

$$\left(\forall i.\ x_i = 1\right) \lor \left(\forall i.\ x_i = 0\right), \tag{0}$$

such that every $x_i$ is used at most once. It is doable for $n \leq 1$, but impossible otherwise, i.e. for $n > 1$. Let's assume that a Boolean function $f(x_0,\ldots)$ uses $x_0$ only once, then $f$ is increasing in $x_i$ or $f$ is decreasing in $x$, more formally

$$\forall (x_i)\subset\{0,1\}^n.\ f(0,x_1,\ldots) \leq f(1,x_1,\ldots), \tag{1}$$

or

$$\forall (x_i)\subset\{0,1\}^n.\ f(0,x_1,\ldots) \geq f(1,x_1,\ldots). \tag{2}$$

The reason being, operators $\lor$ and $\land$ are monotonic and if $x_0$ is used only once, then there is a constant number $k_0$ of negations along the way. $\mathtt{NAND}$ is just $\mathtt{NOT} \circ \mathtt{AND}$, and if $k_0$ is even then (1), and for $k_0$ odd we have (2).

By symmetry, it is the same for $x_i$ for any $i$. However, the desired operation $equiv(x_0,x_1,x_2)$ does not fulfill (1) or (2), e.g.

\begin{align}
equiv(0,0) &= 1 \\
equiv(1,0) &= 0 \\
equiv(0,1) &= 0 \\
equiv(1,1) &= 1
\end{align}

Concluding, $equiv(x_0,\ldots)$ for $n > 1$ does not fulfill (1) or (2) and thus is not expressible in terms of $\lor, \land,\neg$ with variables being used only once.

I hope it answers your question ;-)

Comment: please verify my answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no expression of the form $(a *_1 b) *_2 c$ where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are arbitrary bits and $*_1$ and $*_2$ are one of the bitwise operators $and$, $or$, $xor$ or their negations $nand$, $nor$ and $nxor$ that evaluates to true whenever $a = b = c$. I've used a program to test that all possible choices of $*_1$ and $*_2$ will not give the desired output in all cases.

https://gist.github.com/timjb/6587803

Answer (score 0):

(a xor b)'.(b xor c)'
= (a'b+b'a)'(b'c+c'b)'
= (a'b+b'a+b'c+c'b)'
= (b(a'+c')+b'(a+c))'
= (b(a.c)'+b'(a'c')')'
= (b xor (a and c))'

Comment: btw someone pls edit it properly... im on mobile. thank you! :)

Comment: Your final expression is just $\neg (b \oplus (a \wedge c))$, or $b \equiv (a \wedge c)$.  This isn't the same as $(b \equiv a) \wedge (b \equiv c)$.  For instance, they differ when $a=1$ and $b=c=0$.

Comment: As mjqxxxx pointed out, this is not correct, e.g. for $(a,b,c) = (1,0,0)$ it outputs $1$.

Comment: hmm... true. where might be the glitch?

Comment: i understand the last step i did is wrong, when i change it to xor format. :/ wrong lead...